# Implement custom Kafka Consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a kafka consumer which receive latest messages published on that topic. The code is below:

```
topic = my_topic;
KafkaConsumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton(topic));
try {
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = KafkaConsumer.poll(10);
            for(ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord : consumerRecords){
                LOGGER.info("proceess mesage received from kafka topic=" + topic);
                System.out.println(consumerRecord.value());
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        throw new KafkaException(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Therefore, I want to get rid of while loop and implement a wrapper like this:

```
customConsumer((x) - > {
    System.out.println("I have received " + x + "from kafka topic");
});
//run code
```

Everytime when a message is published, the customConsumer method will know about the new message, this method will listens everytime on kafka topic. I have tried with ExecutorService but without success. Any ideea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understood the question fully, but here goes:

```
void customConsumer(java.util.function.Consumer<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> consumer) {
    KafkaConsumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton(topic));
    try {
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = KafkaConsumer.poll(10);
            for(ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord : consumerRecords){
                consumer.accept(consumerRecord);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        throw new KafkaException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

you can then call this method like you described:

```
customConsumer(x -> {
    System.out.println("I have received " + x + " from kafka topic");
});
```

You only need and ExecutorService, etc. if you want to do something in parallel to the processing of messages or if you want to process the messages concurrently in multiple threads. If so, I'd suggest you have a look at [akka-stream-kafka](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/consumer.html) and their examples using .mapAsync(). They also make it easy to do things like committing the offsets back to kafka correctly (also in batches, for a performance gain), which would get error-prone if you do it manually while processing messages in multiple threads.